# Datepicker - onClose doesn't run

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need help with my UI element. I want to show next calendar when first close.
Unfortunately function onClose doesnt run :/ I don't know why..

```
$(function () {
    $('#datepickerDate1').datepicker({
        onClose: function () {
            $("#datepickerDate2").datepicker("show");
        }
    });
});
```

Website online:
http://nauka.cf/issue/ui-elements/search-box-1/index.html

Thanks!

Comment: so we are talking about https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ which is worth mentioning I guess

Comment: What makes you think that 'onClose' would work? Should you not work with events as mentioned in the docs https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html Or am I looking at the wrong plugin after all?

Comment: Only see `onHide` in the docs, there is no `onClose`

Answer (score 0):

Try following will solved your issue.

```
$("#datepickerDate2").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

solve:

```
 $(function () {
    $('#datepickerDate1').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
      $('#datepickerDate1').datepicker('hide');
      $('#datepickerDate2').datepicker('show');
    });
  });
```